# Unable to match group in apex regex

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

I am trying to dynamically match a string against other string.

```
String badWord = 'badwords';
String comment = 'I talk badwords and goodwords';
Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile('((.*)('+badWord+')(.*))');
Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher(comment);
System.debug('matcher '+MyMatcher);
while(MyMatcher.find()){
   System.debug(MyMatcher.group());  
}
```

I assumed atleast 4 groups to be matched against, however I get only one group and that too full string.

```
I talk badwords and goodwords
```

Comment: The pattern matcher implementation is somewhat limited in Apex. Why do you need to capture the parts of the string that are not the "bad words"?

Comment: @PhilW I want to get location of "bad words" so that I can highlight it in later contexts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did get four groups, you just didn't check for them. The `group()` method returns `group(0)`, which matches outer parentheses group. To get the full picture, you'd check out:

```
while(MyMatcher.find()){
    for(Integer i = 0, s = MyMatcher.groupCount(); i <= s; i++) {
        System.debug(MyMatcher.group(i));  
    }
}
```

Which gives you:

```
USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|I talk badwords and goodwords
USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|I talk badwords and goodwords
USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|I talk 
USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|badwords
USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG| and goodwords
```

Where `group(0)` gives you the complete match, `group(1)` matches the outer parentheses (the first capture group), `group(2)` matches the first inner parentheses, `group(3)` gives you the `badwords`, and `group(4)` captures the last capture group.

This output is essentially the same as it is in JavaScript.

If you want to match all of the `badwords`, don't use the outer capture groups with `find()`.

```
Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile('('+badWord+')');
```

Doing this will get you just the badwords, and using the `start()` method will tell you the starting offset of the previous match from `find()`.

If you instead want to find all of the matches one at a time, the pattern should be:

```
Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile('(.*?)('+badWord+')');
```

Which gives the output:

```
USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|I talk badwords
USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|I talk 
USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|badwords
```

If there were more matches for badwords, you'd get successive strings in the order `(goodwords)(badwords)`.